# Returning array/list type function of WCF in ASP.NET page with return type same as Linq to Entity Class types

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I want to access the data of table using WCF services.

My code is like:

The table name is marital_status and have relations with other tables.

```
    [OperationContract] 
    marital_status[] GetMartialStatus();

    public marital_status[] GetMartialStatus()
    {
        using (HREntities context = new HREntities())
        {
            marital_status[] obj = context.marital_status.ToArray();

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

When i try to use this:

```
  List<marital_status> asd =   EntityService.ServiceInstance.GetMartialStatus().ToList();
```

I got the error that context is no longer available.

I am using array then there should not be any problem.

PLEASE NOTE: I dont want to create DATA CONTRACTS etc. Because Linq to Entities already expose the classes for the tables.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE:

If i explicitly remove LAZY LOADING = false in the code my code starts working. But i do not want to remove this

Comment: When you say you try to use the above code "EntityService.ServiceInstance" you get an error, where are you getting the error. Would be helpful if you can post more code which is near to the actual sceanrio. If things work for array of objects then i dont see any problem with list being used.

Comment: @Rajesh i am getting this error in EDMX designer cs file where relationships like primary key is defined

Comment: Is EntityService.ServiceInstance your web service class. If possible can you post the complete code of your service class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any relations between marital_status and other entities?
Maybe you should include them in the result or explicitly load them?

```
marital_status[] obj = context.marital_status.Include("other_relation").ToArray();
```

or

```
foreach(var ob in obj)
    ob.Load(relation);
```

If you modify data, you may also want to try `context.marital_status.MergeOption(MergeOption.NoTracking);`

Btw, your method is named Martial and relation is Marital ;-)

Comment: thats not the good approach isnt it. my tables may have 25 other tables linked in this case it is more resource consuming and dont know how much time consuming

Comment: It's true, but than you may try to null relations to other tables you don't want to use - not tried tough, you'll have to check it.

Comment: Btw, as far as I remember, you cannot just set null to the relational properties, but you may create a shallow copy of an object, manualy. It should be quite an easy solution.